# What do you think about my PSU design?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, bjt, power-electronics, lm317

I have designed a symetrical PSU using LM317, LM337 plus power BJTs. The desired output range is at least 24V-2V @ 6A max. Altough not shown in the schematic, i plan to add power resistors and a rotary switch to provide current limiting. What do you think about it? Is there some better way of limiting current, without high power pots, JFETs and resistors?
[image: schematic]

Comment: With 6A the Cap ripple current rating may be exceeded greatly.  Also dV=10ms* 2A/ 4.7mF=4V decay on peak input

Comment: That's okay, the voltage would be 28V, still over my reqiurements.

Comment: Your transformer says 12-0-12 so you'll be lucky to get +/-9V out of it at a few A. P-P ripple will be 0.05*6A/0.047F = 6.3V, plus a diode drop plus the drop across your LM317 etc. plus a drop across the pass transistor (that gets you down to a few volts out). Also pay attention to Tony's comment about ripple current rating or your capacitors will die early.

Comment: Oh dear, i thought that if I measured 24V AC from my transformer end to end i will get a wee bit more DC out of it, around 33V peat with no load

Comment: Don't underestimate the challenges with linear unregulated to 3.2V dropout regulator. Consider the buck version of the this circuit https://www.homemade-circuits.com/lm317-variable-switch-mode-power-supply/

Comment: What do I think of this design? I think it is about 40-years antiquated (LM317 was introduced in 1976). It is generally recognized that electronics design and component base changes about every 5 years to an extent that requires re-training of electrical engineers. So this design is about 8 generations behind. What would be a reason to live in such deep past? I know it is not nice, but truth should be told.

Comment: I understand you sir, but the reason I decided to use this design is its simplicity and low cost. I know that SMPS are better more efficient, etc but in my opinion they are much harder to design by yourself, at least for me - I'm not too expirienced.

Comment: A design stands and falls on the expectations placed on it. What is the full spec for what your design is aiming for. This includes all the normal things but also noise level, drift with temperature, ageing, transient recovery expectations, heat loss, physical size, immunity to EMI. That is why you cannot expect a proper answer to this question.

Comment: I need at least 24V and 4A output, stabilized. I'm going to use an EMI filter on the mains side. I'm also going to use inductive loads (motors etc). What is  transient recovery?

Comment: @thegamebusterpl - You should listen to yourself more closely. "around 33V peat with no load" Right you are. But then you go and spoil the effect by talking about a 6 A output. See the problem? (And yes, you may now facepalm. But don't worry, we all do at first. If you're any good the rate will go down with experience.)